# I have a problem with bayes and train lines

Tags: self-study, multinomial-distribution, descriptive-statistics, bayes

I have this problem which I can't fully understand it:

> Assume you have entered in a foreign city of unknown size. At entrance
>   you see a tramcar with number $100$. Let us assume that the tramcar
>   lines of the city are numbered with integers starting from one, and
>   that every line has an equal probability of being spotted. What can
>   you learn about the number of tramcar lines on the basis of your
>   observation. Notice that this problem is a discrete version of the
>   previous one. Assuming that the number of tramcar lines $\theta$ is
>   large, you can approximate sums with integrals and use the following
>   general result:
>
> $$\int_k^{\infty} t^{-m}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{k^{(1-m)}}{m - 1}$$
>
> For instance, you can use a prior of the form $\theta^{-1}$ and
>   calculate the posterior median.

Now I know how to do it with considering one line, so I will get the median if there only exist one, but multiple I'm lost, and I think is with multinomial distr. But I'm not sure how to set it up, I have read the [German tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) which it sounded similar and the explanation was very intuitive and clear, I was hoping for one more or less like so, I'm not an statistician, more a programmer dealing with bayes atm. Any help? Thanks.